# What's the most fail-proof way of dynamically acquiring a widget's internal Tcl/Tk class name?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

What's the most fail-proof way of dynamically fetching a `widget`'s internal Tcl/Tk class name?

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    from tkinter import ttk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    widget = ttk.Combobox(root)    # Would be "TCombobox" in this case
    widget.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

This is only base widget though, please consider deep inheriting classes of this `widget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`widget.winfo_class()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_class-method) method:

> **winfo_class()**
>
> Returns the Tkinter widget class name for this widget. If the widget
>   is a Tkinter base widget, `widget.winfo_class()` is the same as
>   `widget.__class__.__name__`.

---

```
widget = ttk.Combobox()
print(widget.winfo_class())
# output: TCombobox
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `widget`'s newly created one way would be to use `bindtags` `tagList` element to acquire as in:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    from tkinter import ttk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    widget = ttk.Combobox(root)
    widget['values'] = widget.bindtags()[1]
    widget.current(0)
    widget.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

However, this *would* fail if the default `tagList` returned by `bindtags()` is modified.